# Overlaying two scatter plots with different color scales in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay two scatter plots in ggplot2. The goal is to make the outside part of dots colored according to one variable (6 categories, factor) and the inside filled with a gradient color of another continuous variable (numeric).

I wrote two pieces of code, each works on its own (please see screenshots below).

```
    ggplot(PCA_isotopes_2, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
              theme_classic() +
              geom_point(aes(color = factor(subspecies)), shape = 1, size = 2.95, stroke=1, alpha=5/6) +
              scale_color_manual(breaks = c("gutturalis", "rg.hybrids", "rt", "rustica", "tg", "tytleri"), values=c("#0066CC", "#9933CC", "#FFCC99", "#CC0000", "#33CC99", "#FFFF00")) 

ggplot(PCA_isotopes_2, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
          theme_classic() +  
          geom_point(aes(color = carbon.ratio), size = 2.88, alpha=5/6) +
          scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "yellow")
```

[image]

[image]

When I try to overlay them this way:

```
    p <- ggplot(PCA_isotopes_2, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(aes(color = carbon.ratio), size = 2.88, alpha=5/6) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "yellow")

    p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(subspecies)), shape = 1, size = 2.95,         stroke=1, alpha=5/6) +
    scale_color_manual(breaks = c("gutturalis", "rg.hybrids", "rt", "rustica", "tg", "tytleri"), values=c("#0066CC", "#9933CC", "#FFCC99", "#CC0000", "#33CC99", "#FFFF00"))
```

I get error messages:

"Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which
will replace the existing scale.
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale".

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure out why it doesn't work. I will very appreciate help!

Thanks,
Georgy

Answer (score 3):

In general you can only map an aesthetic once. Here is a workaround that uses a `fill` aesthetic for the continuous variable as an alternative, with `shape = 21`. However, I would prefer to map to a different aesthetic, such as `shape`, entirely, as in the second version.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(colour = Species),
    shape = 1,
    size = 3,
    stroke = 2,
    alpha = 5 / 6
    ) +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(fill = Sepal.Length, colour = NA),
    size = 2.88,
    alpha = 5 /6,
    shape = 21
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "yellow")
```

[image]

```r
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(colour = Sepal.Length, shape = Species),
    size = 3,
    alpha = 5 / 6
  ) +
  scale_colour_viridis()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much, the first example does exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to assign custom colors to the first geom_point?

Comment: yes, i took them out because it looked even more unreadable but you're welcome to put scale_colour_manual back in

Comment: Indeed, the second version looks better. One last question - how is it possible to assign custom shapes there? I tried this: ggplot(PCA_isotopes_2, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(colour = carbon.ratio, shape = subspecies),
    size = 2,
    alpha = 5 / 6,
    scale_shape_manual(breaks = c("gutturalis", "rg.hybrids", "rt", "rustica", "tg", "tytleri"), values = c(0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3))
  ) +
  scale_colour_viridis()    And get an error "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class ScaleDiscrete/Scale/ggproto"